# A question about switching a hard drive to a different laptop

Tags: grub2, hard-drive

I own an old laptop which i have Windows alongside dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and one time last year which i had my laptop dual booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.04 and moved the HDD to one of my other laptops, the GRUB was overwritten and i couldn't access any OS which i didn't care about that time back then because i was planning to format the whole HDD and reinstall Windows but thats not really the case. Because i have many important files (some of them are backed up to my Google Drive) and i have made huge scores on Windows Store games and since that laptop as i said got dual boot Ubuntu 20.04, if i move the HDD to another laptop i got, will the GRUB be overwritten and can't access my operating systems again like last time?

Comment: Windows major updates can sometimes overwrite grub, but usually only stops from choosing Ubuntu.  A simple re-install of grub from USB is the fixed.  Moving the drive to another machine usually won't overwrite grub, but the new machine might not recondize the drive as boot.  Will need more information.  Can usually boot a machine with Ubuntu installer in live mode and see any other drives attached.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change your hard drive, assuming it's the right physical size, but you really ought to format the disk and cleanly install the operating system on the new hardware, unless the computers are identical hardware.

It's not a good practice to yank a hard drive from one computer and attempt to transplant it into an entirely different device.  The operating system was installed on the "old" laptop *tailored for that laptop's hardware*.